# MySQL statements for this date last year

Tags: php, mysql

I'm confused about these php mysql statements.

I need to get four different results from the same column(amount) in a table.

The functions find the sum of (amount) for the following:
Year to date
Giving time last year
Total giving last year
Giving in the last 30 days

They all seem to be variations of the same. I don't know how to get LastYearNow to show the correct results. How do I show results from the beginning of 2016 to today's date 2016?

```
public function getSum() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ");           
       return $query->row; 
}
    public function lastThirty() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH)" );            
       return $query->row; 
}
public function lastYearNow() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added >= (CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH) ");           
       return $query->row; 
}
    public function lastYearTotal() {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where YEAR(date_added) = YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR))" );           
       return $query->row; 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query for `lastYearNow` is currently calculating the last 12 months of totals. If, instead, you want to calculate last year's totals from the 1st of the year to the current date, you'll need to use a BETWEEN clause:

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum 
FROM donate 
WHERE date_added BETWEEN 
MAKEDATE(YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), 1, 1)
AND
(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)
```

Caveat: I don't have a MySQL install in front of me, so the syntax may not be quite right.

Comment: tried this in phpmyadmin getting errors for MAKEDATE not sure how i'd write this in a php query I tried :  $query = $this->db->query("SELECT SUM(amount) as amount_sum FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "donate Where date_added BETWEEN 
MAKEDATE(YEAR(DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)), 1, 1)
AND
(CURDATE() - INTERVAL 12 MONTH)" );

Comment: It seems to work when I remove a comma and a 1. Thanks a lot man!